# Reverse key values using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given I have the following object

```
{
    "a": ["100", "200"],
    "b": ["100"],
    "c": ["100", "200", "300"],
    "d": ["200"]
}
```

How can I reverse it so instead of being key to a list of values, it's a value to a list of the corresponding keys, like so:

```
{
    "100": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "200": ["a", "c", "d"],
    "300": ["c"]
}
```

I've tried `_.reverse` but that literally just reversed the keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the current object by values and check if key is present in the reduced key's array or not if absent then add it.

```js
const obj = {
    "a": ["100", "200"],
    "b": ["100"],
    "c": ["100", "200", "300"],
    "d": ["200"]
};

const groupedResult = Object.entries(obj)
.reduce((r, [key, val]) => {
    val.forEach((item) => {
        if (!r[item]) {
            r[item] = [key];
        } else {
            if (!r[item].includes(key)) {
                r[item].push(key);
            }
        }
    });
    
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(groupedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_.reduce()` and `_.forEach()`

```js
const data = {
  a: ["100", "200"],
  b: ["100"],
  c: ["100", "200", "300"],
  d: ["200"],
}

const res = _.chain(data)
  .reduce((result, value = [], key) => {
    _.forEach(value, (v) => {
      result[v] = [...(result[v] || []), key]
    })
    return result
  }, {})
  .value()

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can reduce it backwards to create a hash as result, and keep update that. if you found the key (what was your value) in map, fetch the value of that key in your map and add the current one, otherwise create a empty array and add the current one.

Here is a snippet with lodash (in lidash you can directly apply `_.reduce` on a object.

```js
let obj = {
    "a": ["100", "200"],
    "b": ["100"],
    "c": ["100", "200", "300"],
    "d": ["200"]
};

let res = _.reduce(obj, (r, e, k) => e.reduce((_, n) => (r[n] = (r[n] || [])).push(k) && r, r), {});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Well, now I have used lodash here, so I can directly apply reduce on the Object, otherwise you can convert it (object input) to entries and apply vanilla JS reduce on the entries. so the code before the first reduce will be changed slightly here, see this plain JS version without lodash:

```js
let obj = {
    "a": ["100", "200"],
    "b": ["100"],
    "c": ["100", "200", "300"],
    "d": ["200"]
};

let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, e]) => e.reduce((_, n) => (r[n] = (r[n] || [])).push(k) && r, r), {});

console.log(res);
```